# Get-EventLog -List shows wrong Max size of Event Logs?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, powershell, windows-server-2016

I'm working with logs a bit and it seems that Get-EventLog is not able to show real Max size. It's taking max that is set via "old" gpo settings.

[image]

Just for fun I've set the event log size to 2TB and i can seee that current size is 6GB so more then 4gb that is shown by Get-EventLog.

[image]

[image]

Anyone knows a reason for this? Or I'm using wrong command? Or misreading results?

[image: Descr]

Same type of answer when using WMI...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the proper way to do it is to use [Get-WinEvent](https://evotec.xyz/get-eventlog-shows-wrong-maximum-size-of-event-logs/). It returns proper values.

```
$results = @()
foreach ($computer in $computers) {
    $results += Get-WinEvent -ListLog Security -ComputerName $computer | Select MaximumSizeInBytes, FileSize, IsLogFul, LastAccessTime, LastWriteTime, OldestRecordNumber, RecordCount, LogName, LogType, LogIsolation, IsEnabled, LogMode
}

Write-Host "Get-WinEvent TEST"
$results | ft -AutoSize
```

Here's a useful link to [Everything you wanted to know about event logs](https://evotec.xyz/powershell-everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-event-logs/) that I've created after working with Windows Events for a year. It will save people's time and pain I had to go thru.